# If a sequence of random variables all have the same mean, is the sequence tight?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose $(X_n)$ are almost surely non-negative random variables all with the same finite mean $\mu$. Is this sequence necessarily tight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this follows directly from Markov's inequality: $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq R ) =\mathbb{P}(X_n \geq R) \leq \frac{\mu}{R}\qquad \text{for any $R>0$}.$$

Consequently,

$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq R) \stackrel{R \to \infty}{\to} 0.$$